# MySql - innodb - How row level lock on composite key worked in simple words

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb, latitude-longitude, table-locking

Folks, I read the reference manual of MySQL 5.5 but its very tricky to understand row level lockings. I am using MySQL innoDB and want to understand the row level locking on a table which has composite primary key. Both keys are identifying keys of one-to-one from parent table.

Here is the table example
[image]

I want to run Haversine formula (I know the query and formula) on the above table such that in where clause I have to provide trip_route_id. such that Haversine formula query run on particular trip_route_id.

on the other hand some threads/sessions are inserting into this table while some are searching. I have a default PRIMARY index  on both PK columns.

Now The question: Will my complete table is locked or only the Rows locked which has trid_route_id = someProvidedId?

**Edit:** Index of PK column.
[image]

Please Let me know if some other explanation required?

Thanks.

Comment: Is `trip_routes_id` the first or second column in the index?

Comment: I believe its second column. see my edit.

Comment: Then it won't be able to lock the row in the index. A prefix of a composite index acts as an index by itself, but a suffix does not.

Comment: So , I need to change column order as well columns in index?

Comment: Or you could add another index for this column.

Comment: Will not 2nd index slow down the insertion?

Comment: Probably. It's a tradeoff.

Comment: I have no problem of altering the sequence of columns in PK index. So I have  changed it. But I am not sure how to verify that row level locking is applied against a particular trip_id .

Comment: Not sure how to verify this, but there's detailed information about InnoDB locking [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html)

Comment: I think you can generally assume that if it *can* use a record lock in the index, it will.

Answer (score 0):

Row level locking is not the problem.

You are searching for "nearby" things using latitude and longitude?

Well, without any extra effort, that will require a table scan, which is slower and slower as the table grows.

Add a "bounding box" to your `WHERE` clause.  If that does not speed things up enough, then come back with the query and the table size.  Example of a using a bounding box:

```
WHERE lat BETWEEN 45.45 - 0.77 AND 45.45 + 0.77
  AND lng BETWEEN 99.11 - 1.11 AND 99.11 + 1.11
```

will filter down to items within about 50 miles of (45.45, 99.11).  The 'box' is approximately a square.  Adding on a distance check would let you get "within a radius of xx miles/km".

Comment: Sorry Rick, I get this message late. Now regarding the point table will get bigger and bigger, actually we are also deleting the coordinates which is not active anymore, so basically this table only contains all those coordinates which belongs to active trip, and every trip can have maximum of 10, 15 points. 

So my concerns was on searching and deleting. that when some service is deleting some of the rows, I do not want that the whole table is locked by delete call, i want that only the rows which have desired trip id should only be locked and deleted while some service is searching .

Comment: I will search about bounding box, currently have no idea about this term and usage.

Comment: @Mubasher - With InnoDB, deleting a few rows, even a hundred rows, is so fast that it should not be a concern.  Deleting a million rows gets dicey.  Searching a few, or a hundred, rows with lat/lng is also so fast as not to be a problem.

Comment: @Mubasher - I added an example of using a "bounding box".